# Websocket: Browser dosn't seem to receive data from python server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm working on creating a websocket server via python (I'm kinda new to python) and I've made a significant progress, but I am unable to send data to the web browser. I can establish a connection and receive data from the browser, but I cannot send back data. The browser just ignores it. I would assume that if the browser received a package that didn't follow the specifications, it would terminate the connection, but the connection stays active.

Here is the method I am using to encode the data into the frame:

```
def encode_message(data):
    frame = "\x81"
    size = len(data)
    if size * 8 <= 125:
        frame += chr(size)
    else:
        raise Exception("Uh, oh. Strings larger than 125 bits are not supported")

    return frame + data
```

I am sending the data using `sock.sendall(framed_data)`. What could be the problem? The data for a message like "yo" ends up being `10000001 00000010 01111001 01101111` (spaces added for improved readability). Why doesn't the browser accept a message like this? Doesn't it follow the guidelines outlined in [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6455/?include_text=1#5.2.%20%20Base%20Framing%20Protocol)? I am trying to support the most recent websocket version which I believe to be version 13. I am using python version 2.7.3.

I have tried to look at python websocket libraries' source code, but all of them seem to implement a deprecated version of the websocket protocol that has been shown to have vulnerabilities.

Here is the code that calls the function above:

```
def send(data):
    frame = encode_message(data)
    print "Sending all..."
    sock.sendall(frame) #Socket that handles all communications with client
    print "Frame sent :)"
    return
```

I also downloaded wireshark to sniff the packages sent between the server and the socket. The packages sent by my server are identical to those sent from a server that is accepted by the browser. I couldn't see any difference at all. (I looked directly at the hex source)

Comment: So no one knows how to fix this?

Comment: What callbacks run in your browser?  Does `onopen` run at the end of your handshake?  Do `onerror` or `onclose` run later?  Are you remembering to keep the connection open after completing your handshake?  If none of these questions help you towards an answer, can you post your full server source plus some simple client code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `onopen` does run at the end of my handshake. `onclose` does not run until the websocket is disconnected by the server. `onerror` is never called because no error is thrown. After the handshake is made, the server can receive messages from the client, but the reverse is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem! It took hours of unfun debugging and messing with my code. After closely examining the packages sent back and forth between the server and client I finally realized that there was a problem with my server's connection upgrade response. Whenever it computed a hash, it also added a `\n` to the end of it. That resulted in a `\n\r\n` at the end of one of the lines. The client interpreted that as the end of that transmission and everything that followed was parsed using WebSocket protocol. I had another line after that in the header, so it totally messed up my communications with the client. I could still read from the client, but if I tried to write to the client, the data would get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

The second byte of your transmitted message (and the length check in your code) looks wrong.  The length of a message is in *bytes*, not bits.

From [RFC6455 §5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) (my emphasis)

> Payload length:  7 bits, 7+16 bits, or 7+64 bits
>
> The length of the "Payload data", in **bytes**: if 0-125, that is the
> payload length.

The reason that nothing is received in the browser is that your message claims to have a 16 byte body.  The browser will read the 2 additional bytes you send then block waiting for another 14 bytes that it expects but you don't send.

If you change the second byte to the number of bytes in the message - 0x2 or 00000010 binary - then things should work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, thanks for catching that, but I was still unable to get the browser to receive the message...

Comment: Daft question, but you are sending 4 bytes I take it? (Rather than the binary version of the message you posted as a 32-char string.)  It'd be interesting to see the code that calls `encode_message` then sends the framed data.

Comment: I added the code that calls the function above. The actual string that I'm sending looks like this: `�Ok`.

Comment: By that, I meant that the string would look similar to it. It is not the same as the example above. It was just what I had handy at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any other problems with your code.  The only thing I could guess is that maybe you send some extra data at the end of your handshake that gets in the way of your next message